# watch function expression affect debug in Chrome devtool

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

From Chrome Devtool Example https://googlechrome.github.io/devtools-samples/debug-js/get-started

While adding breakpoint on first line of `inputsAreEmpty` function, `inputsAreEmpty()` into Watch, `inputsAreEmpty()` in watch will invoke.

log will print more times if insert log into `inputsAreEmpty` function, why is this happening?

Comment: Do you mean you have `inputsAreEmpty()` as a Watch expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you have `inputsAreEmpty()` as a Watch expression, that expression will get evaluated (calling `inputsAreEmpty`) any time the Watch needs to update its display. If you put a breakpoint in `inputsAreEmpty`, Watch needs to update its display when it hits the breakpoint — which means calling `inputsAreEmpty`, which will hit the breakpoint, and so on, and so on, and so on.

In general, it's best not to have function calls in Watch expressions (though there are exceptions to that). But you definitely need to avoid having function calls in Watch expressions you have breakpoints in, because it creates the vicious cycle above.